# Buscar String Aleatória no SQLite e depois mostrar o Resultado na Tela com botão

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

// Criar Banco de Dados.
        final SQLiteDatabase bancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase("Nome tabela", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

```
    // Criar Tabela.

    bancoDados.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  questions(id INT(3),perguntas VARCHAR)");

    // Inserir Dados. ( Crl+d para duplicar INSERT INTO ).

   // bancoDados.execSQL("INSERT INTO questions(id,perguntas) VALUES (1,'Posso ser cromado 1')");
   // bancoDados.execSQL("INSERT INTO questions(id,perguntas) VALUES (2,'Posso ser cromado 2')");


    // Puxar os dados da Tabela.

    bt_perguntar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    Cursor cursor = bancoDados.rawQuery("" +
                    "SELECT perguntas " +
                    "FROM questions " +
                    "ORDER BY RANDOM() " +
                    "LIMIT 1;",
            null);


    int indicePerguntas = cursor.getColumnIndex("perguntas");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor != null){

        text_pergunta.setText(cursor.getString(indicePerguntas));
        cursor.moveToNext();

        //Log.i("RESULTADO - Pergunta ",cursor.getString(indicePerguntas));
    }

        }
    });
```

Erro do log.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A idéia é funcionar assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não coloque o código em imagem. Depois edite a sua pergunta e insira o código em texto.

Comment: Andrei achei assim mais simples, sou novo aqui. Seria pra poder copiar o código e efetuar testes? e Obter uma resposta?

Comment: Exato Guil! Desta forma você também aumenta suas chances de alguém te responder! Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só você usar dentro do `Cursor` essa `query` que irá funcionar e você poderá usar o cursor:

```
    Cursor cursor = bancoDados.rawQuery("" +
            "SELECT perguntas " +
            "FROM questions " +
            "ORDER BY RANDOM() " +
            "LIMIT 1;", 
            null);
```

Comment: Andrei, bom dia. Funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria. Fiquei um dia quebrando a cabeça. Conhecimento é poder. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: @GuilDraco tranquilo. Não esquece de aprovar ! Tem um sinal de ✔ na resposta para você aprovar. Fica no topo do lado esquerdo da resposta, abaixo do sinal de UP e DOWN.

Comment: Sem querer abusar, Rsrs.. Tem algum tópico aqui que mostra como eu poderia exibir esse texto selecionado na tela do projeto ao clicar o botão? Eu tentei, mas ai zoa tudo.Usando text_pergunta.setText(cursor.getString(indicePerguntas));
                cursor.moveToNext();  no lugar do log. ele seta o texto mas só quando fecha e abre o app. Queria adicionar isso ao evento do clique. Brigadão, abraços. Já me salvou. Rsrsr

Comment: @GuilDraco então, não entendi direito o que você quer... Poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: @GuilDraco vi só agora... Então... é melhor você inserir o erro que aparece no log. Pois podem ter vários motivos para isso acontecer. É impossível detectar o erro apenas com o código que você passou como uma resposta.  Coloque o erro na pergunta! E depois apague a resposta que você postou ok?

Comment: Valeu Andrei, acho que já apagaram, sabia nem que tinh como apagarem, Rsrs. Ta na contagem aqui pra deletar, algo assim. Atualizei com o erro do log. e o trecho do cód. e o que estou querendo. Brigadão pela força, e já ajudou muito com a questão de setar aleatório relaxa. Rss

Comment: @GuilDraco tranquilo amigo! =) Depois veja esta resposta >  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316390/9303032 seu problema é o mesmo.